# What does Play Framework 1 use for ORM Implementation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, playframework, playframework-1.x

what ORM does Play Framework version 1 use? From what I read from the site, it mentions JPA, when I search JPA I couldn't find the download site for the ORM framework. CMIIW, JPA seems to be a feature from Java and not a ready to use ORM framework.

does Play uses Hibernate? If yes, how could I create the model class in Java and the table in the database is automatically created? How do I use the .find() method in Hibernate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Play Framework 1.x uses Hibernate. You extend Play's Model support class, mark your objects with necessary annotations, and Play takes care of the rest. Take a look at Play documentation, for example chapter [Persist your object model with Hibernate](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/model#hibernate) or [JPA persistence: Finding objects](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jpa#finding) - those should answer your questions.

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply. Then does Play framework put their on implementation on the .find() method like the show on their tutorial? Because I try to learn Hibernate and that seems to be no .find() implementation but HQL instead.

Comment: Yes, when you extend `play.db.jpa.Model` you get the necessary helper methods in your model (these actually come from `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` which `Model` extends). Methods such as find, validate, save, delete etc.

Comment: You will see that the find method just throws a UnsupportedOperationException, it is actually replaced by the `JPAEnhancer` which forwards the calls to `play.db.jpa.JPQL` which builds the queries.